# R iconv() error -unsupported conversion from 'latin1' to 'ASCII'

Tags: r, domc

I want to install the R package "doMC", and the code is

`install.packages("doMC", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

and then I get the following error:

```
Error in iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII") : unsupported conversion from 'latin1' to 'ASCII'
```

So, how do I resolve the issue?

My OS is :

```
Linux version 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-023.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Sep 16 01:56:35 EDT 2014
```

and my R version :

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
```

Comment: [Latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) **is** ASCII,or rather, an extension of the 7-bit [US-ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). There's no reason for such a conversion. Why do you want to perform that conversion? What are you trying to do? Did you try to read something with the wrong codepage perhaps? If you get mangled text it means you used the *wrong* codepage to read the file. Or you used ASCII to read Unicode.

Comment: Please describe the *actual* problem, post your code, the input, output text and what you expected.

Comment: Have you tried installing from CRAN?